# UIButton looks good in InterfaceBuilder, but not on iPad sim or device

Tags: iphone, ipad, interface-builder

In InterfaceBuilder, I'm creating the simplest possible UIButton, by simply dragging from the Library panel into my view. After doing that, I get a nice UIButton that looks like this:

[Pretty image http://img683.imageshack.us/img683/760/screenshot20100410at111g.png](http://img683.imageshack.us/img683/760/screenshot20100410at111g.png)

When I preview in the simulator, or view on my iPad device, my UIButton has a line underneath it, like this:

[Ugly image http://img532.imageshack.us/img532/8863/screenshot20100410at111.png](http://img532.imageshack.us/img532/8863/screenshot20100410at111.png)

Anyone else have this problem? Anyone have a fix?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is *by-design*. iPad's UI is different from iPhone anyway.

If you don't want the shadow, create a custom (stretchable) background image.